# Residual specification for xtmixed

Tags: stata, random-effects-model

Suppose a random intercept model is to be fitted, like:
$$y_{ij}=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1ij} + \beta_2x_{2ij} + \beta_3x_{3ij}+ u_{0j} + \epsilon_{ij}$$
where $x_{1ij}$ and $x_{2ij}$ are continuous variables, $x_{3ij}$ can only assume values of 1 and 0, while $u_{0j}$, $\epsilon_{ij}$ are mutually independent and normal.

In a paper I saw such a model being fit using the following two commands in Stata:

```
xtmixed y x1 x2 x3 || groupid:, mle
xtmixed y x1 x2 x3 || groupid:, mle, residuals(independent, by(x3))
```

What does the second command add compared to the first? The estimated coefficients are different amongst the models, and there is some extra output for the random effect parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is an appropriate question for this forum since it deals only with the use of a particular software package, but the option

```
residuals(independent, by(x3))
```

specifies that the residuals are independent, but that their variance may differ according to variable `x3`.  IOW, residuals for observations with different values of `x3` may have different variance.  This is a way to model heteroskedasticity.  It is explained in detail in the section of the [User's Manual [ME]](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/me.pdf) dealing with `mixed` (FYI, the command `xtmixed` was renamed `mixed` in Stata 13).

Comment: Is the model fitted by the second command the same as I have written above - if not, how is it written as?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  As you've written it above, both commands fit exactly the same model (the /// comments out the remainder of the line and continues on to the next).  I suspect that the line continuation originally broke the line with the residuals() option appearing on the next line, and then it got moved up to the first line without removing the line continuation character.  Remove the /// and you should be all set.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the residuals() options was on the next line. Is a different model fitted when the residuals() option is executed? I don't have access to the data set unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, as I indicated above; the second model allows for heteroskedasticity according to different values of x3.